# Rails not recognizing lib files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a `lib/redirect_follower.rb` file

Where I use the file, I include it with `require 'RedirectFollower'`

**But rails is playing hard ball with this error:**

`no such file to load -- RedirectFollower`

**Any clues?** Been banging my head over this for hours. Have tried auto loading all libs using application.rb but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 3):

`require` is for including a *file*, not a class.

You need to `require "redirect_follower"`, ie, the actual filename, not the class name. You may also need to add `lib` to your include path, or `require "lib/redirect_follower"`.

Comment: That strange thing is that it was working originally on Mac but only on a CentOs deploy it's throwing this error.

Comment: It began working on an apache restart for some reason. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In `config/application.rb:` add this:

```
config.autoload_paths << "#{config.root}/lib"
```

With this setting, your modules (i.e. files under lib/) will be automatically required so you don't have to require them anywhere (actually, you should never require them because that would have an negative effect on un/loading files by Rails).

Comment: I have this setting and still have the same issue.